# How do I add a semi-transparent background over an image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I create a semi-transparent layer to place over an image, such as the center of the background on [amarestoudemire.com/](http://amarestoudemire.com/) ([Direct link to background](http://amarestoudemire.com/wp-content/themes/amare/images/bg_ny.jpg))

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS5.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an opacity slider in the Layers explorer.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

fill 51. give fill 51, it's show transparent.

Layer1 = background
Layer2 = shape then give this layer (fill = 52)

Comment: Can you explain a little better? What is "fill 51"?

Comment: A little more explaining wouldn't hurt. Voted down cause I really don't see much effort here.